# Joining two tables, A and B, where the column names of A should be joined with B based on the values of a column in B

Tags: join, database-schema, sql-server-2014

The title is a little confusing, so here is an example of the problem I'm facing.

```
Table:
  FORM_QUESTION
Fields:
  student_id
  q1_ans
  q2_ans
  q3_ans
  q4_ans
  q5_ans

x--------------x----------x----------x----------x----------x----------x
|  student_id  |  q1_ans  |  q2_ans  |  q3_ans  |  q4_ans  |  q5_ans  |
x--------------x----------x----------x----------x----------x----------x
| 1            | A        | D        | B        | B        | E        |
| 2            | D        | C        | B        | A        | D        |
| 3            | B        | C        | D        | A        | B        |
x--------------x----------x----------x----------x----------x----------x
```

The FORM_QUESTION table stores a student's answers for each question.

Here is information on the second table:

```
Table:
  FORM_VALID_ANS
Fields:
  question_id
  valid_answer

x---------------x----------------x
|  question_id  |  valid_answer  |
x---------------x----------------x
|  q1_ans       |  A             |
|  q1_ans       |  B             |
|  q2_ans       |  A             |
|  q2_ans       |  B             |
|  q2_ans       |  C             |
|  q2_ans       |  D             |
|  q3_ans       |  A             |
|  q4_ans       |  A             |
|  q4_ans       |  B             |
|  q5_ans       |  A             |
x---------------x----------------x
```

The second table, FORM_VALID_ANS, stores the valid, acceptable answers for a particular question. So, according to the above table, here is the acceptable list of values for each question:

```
q1_ans: A, B
q2_ans: A, B, C, D
q3_ans: A
q4_ans: A, B
q5_ans: A
```

As you can see, the values for the FORM_VALID_ANS.valid_answer include only the question field names for FORM_QUESTION ("q1_ans", "q2_ans", "q3_ans", "q4_ans", and "q5_ans"). I need to check each students' answer to make sure it is a valid value that they can enter, which is specified in the FORM_VALID_ANS.valid_answer field.

The desired output, where XXX represents an invalid value, and all other values would be answered value:

```
x--------------x----------x----------x----------x----------x----------x
|  student_id  |  q1_ans  |  q2_ans  |  q3_ans  |  q4_ans  |  q5_ans  |
x--------------x----------x----------x----------x----------x----------x
| 1            | A        | D        | XXX      | B        | XXX      |
| 2            | XXX      | C        | XXX      | A        | XXX      |
| 3            | B        | C        | XXX      | A        | XXX      |
x--------------x----------x----------x----------x----------x----------x
```

Is it possible to join these two tables together and produce these results (or similar results)?

Comment: You want what's called a [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: This would be much, much simpler if table FORM_QUESTION were properly normalized, with columns `student_id, question_id, student_answer`. If at all possible, revise your schema! Barring that, yes, you may end up using both pivots *and* unpivots. Ugh.

Comment: I'll look into the pivot. Thanks, Bohemian.

Comment: Philip, thanks for the suggestion, and I totally agree that a properly normalized table would be a much better solution. Unfortunately, this isn't my design and we're receiving similarly structured tables from an outside organization.